# How do you change widths of columns in Android XML?

Tags: xml, android

I have searched this and have not been able to find an answer that works for me.  I currently have 2 columns on my 5th tab.  I would like to make the 1st column 40% and the 2nd column 60% in width.

I tried using android:layout_weight and setting 1 object in column 1 equal to 0.4 and the other on column to equal to 0.6, but to no avail.  Any ideas?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <Button android:text="Start"
                            android:id="@+id/btn_StartWatch"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <Button android:text="Stop"
                            android:id="@+id/btn_StopWatch"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <TextView android:text="TextView"
                              android:id="@+id/tv_ShowResults"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <TextView android:text="TextView2"
                              android:id="@+id/textView2"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <TextView android:text="TextView3"
                              android:id="@+id/textView3"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/details"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:stretchColumns="1"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp">
                        <TableRow>
                            <TextView android:text="Name:" />
                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/txtResName"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ems="10"
                                android:inputType="textPersonName" >
                                <requestFocus />
                            </EditText>
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow>
                            <TextView android:text="Type:" />
                            <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/types">
                                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/chcType1"
                                    android:text="Type 1"/>
                                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/chcType2"
                                    android:text="Type 2"/>
                            </RadioGroup>

                            <TextView android:text="Date:" />
                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/txtResDate"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ems="10"
                                android:inputType="date" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow>
                            <TextView android:text="Time:" />
                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/txtResTime"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ems="10"
                                android:inputType="time" />

                            <TextView android:text="Test" />
                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/txtResNumber"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ems="10"
                                android:inputType="number" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow>
                            <TextView android:text="Test 2" />
                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/txtResTest2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ems="10"
                                android:inputType="phone" />

                            <TextView android:text="Notes:" />
                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/txtResNotes"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:lines="2"
                                android:maxLines="2"
                                android:ems="10"
                                android:maxWidth="200sp"
                                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the layout_width attribute as "0px". Then your layout_weight attribute will dictate the actual width.

Comment: In this case, yes. You need to set either the layout_width or the layout_height (but not both) to 0px anytime you want to use layout weight. When you do that, the attribute you set to 0px (either layout_width or layout_height), will expand to fill the rest of the space.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, with a few modifications.  I added this to TableLayout, instead.  Made width=0px.  Then set weight=100.  I then set each component in the same TableRow, the weight=40 or 50 or whatever.  And set each item width=0px.  Works great!

Comment: Yup, that's the idea. Each LayoutGroup child that uses layout_weight and sets the same [width | height] to 0px will share the width or height. So if one sets weight to 40 and the other to 60, they will take of 40% and 60% of the width or height, respectively.